# How do I parse this PHP to Java using JSON?

Tags: java, php, android, json, parsing

I am pulling my hair out over this. I still don't fully understand how JSON works. I am trying to return a number (formatted as a string) from a PHP script to java. I keep getting the following error:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

This is a snippet from the PHP code:

```
class result
{
    public $value = "";
}

$result = new result();
$result->value = "1";

print(json_encode($result));
```

This returns:
{"value":"1"}

I am trying to store the '1' in a string for error checking purposes on the android side.

It inserts into MySQL database first and that works but it wont return the value correctly.

Here is the java code I have been attempting to use:

```
try 
{
     CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(response="http://test.com/test.php",postParameters);

     String result = response.toString();

     try
     {
          returnString = "";

          JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

          for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
          {
                 JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 Log.i("log_tag","value:"+json_data.getString("value"));

                 returnString = json_data.getString("value");

          }

    }

    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error Parsing",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                                              
    }
}
```

Comment: well do you mean you want to pass json using php to java?

Comment: you´re trying to read an array but it´s a single object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PHP code returns a JSON object (enclosed in `{}`), not an array (enclosed in `[]`). So, you need to change your JSON parsing code as

```
returnString = "";

JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
Log.i("log_tag","value:"+json_data.getString("value"));

returnString = json_data.getString("value");
```

Since, there's only one JSON object being returned, there's no need of the loop too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I´d recomend you to use [Gson API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) which is an amazing API for handling JSON objects. I´d strongly recomend you to read the guides at their website.

The problem here is that you´re trying to convert an object into an array and that´s why you´re getting an Exception. The correct way to convert the value you specified above is:

```
JsonObject jObject = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(value);
```

The example above is using Gson API but the same applies to your API.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this example, this is work for me:

```
public String listOfUser() {
        //User users = new User();

        String URI = "http://localhost/Perumahan/index.php/User_c";
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        List<LinkedHashMap> users = restTemplate.getForObject(URI, List.class);
        //userService.addUser(users);
        return gson.toJson(users);

    }
```